# Add a text to a variable is placed in the front of the variable

Tags: shell-script, variable

With a script we load a file **/Parameters/Param.par**:

Content of Param.par

```
export path_prod=/Directory/A/
```

The contain of the script is:

```
. /Parameters/Param.par
echo $path_prod/log_files.txt
```

My issue is that our output is:

```
log_files.txt/Directory/A/
```

I tested in other machine and the right conversion is done:

```
/Directory/A/log_files.txt
```

Why is it switching the paths? Or if the name is long is it overwriting the begin of my variable?

Comment: Does `Param.par` have Windows-style line endings (CRLF rather than plain LF)?

Comment: Yes it was in CRLF, I delete the last line and press enter again and is working. Did you mind to explain why is working?